# Locationservices

Tags: applications

When in my settings, looking at my apps, I have 2 apps labeled "locationservices" one has absolutely no data. The other does. Do I need both of could I force stop either one?! BTW, my phone is grand x ZTE. If that helps any.

Comment: Those have different app IDs and likely work in conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Did you recently reset your phone with root access ?, in some not well built android platform (ZTE, Colors, Micromax...) Shows such type of behavior. Its not harmful to your phone if u disable, such kind of app with 0 data. 
But here is main issue, If your phone is rooted with softwares like kings root.. That superuser application (other with root permission) can install application which indeed looks same but its function may be spying to ransoming, so please verify that app  from play store or remove asap.